# Using Bootstrap tooltip inside of Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My boss asked me to put a tooltip over the ".datepicker-switch" element, as it is not very intuitive by default (who would've known that you could click that?). I've been scrambling my brains trying to figure out why this isn't working, my JS:

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});

$('.datepicker-switch').tooltip({
  title: "Click here to expand view"
});
```

There are no console errors, the datepicker functions just fine, but no tooltip appears when I hover over the center button at the top (which is the element with the class "datepicker-switch"). How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to reference `.datepicker-switch` but it's not in the DOM yet.

Check the [datepicker events docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html). You can wait for the datepicker to be added to the dom, to do this add a `show`event to the datepicker. Add your tool tip code there.

```
$('#dob').datepicker({ autoclose: true }).on("show", function(e) {
    $('.datepicker-switch').tooltip({
        "title": "Click here to expand view"
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, I had originally thought simply including the tooltip outside of $(document).ready() would have counteracted this, but this solution is much cleaner.